# C# Visual Studio 2015 False Positive From Qihoo-360

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to release a piece of software, the only thing it does which in my eyes which might seem suspicious to an anti virus program is read process memory.
Yet it still triggers a false positive on [this](https://virustotal.com/nb/file/58d7a0f5dee75ee2bea1585dc6e7878f1e0e11538b2c9e3284c25693932fa9fe/analysis/1464839795/) anti virus.

Which to me makes no sense at all, because when I made a completely new WinForms project, completely vanilla. It still triggered a false positive. Which is bad from my point of view. Because it makes it seem like I'm trying to infect the people who download/use my software.

Thanks

Shynd.

Comment: Just a wild guess -- maybe the AV triggers on anything that is not SIGNED code?  Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775519/c-sharp-app-appears-false-positive-in-avg-antivirus

Comment: Thanks, David. I've tried signing the assembly. But, I'll take you up on your answer and check if other people have have the same issue as me (although I did check before posting here). Since it considers a fresh project a hazard I can't be the only one.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow #SOReadyToHelp

Comment: On April 13th 2016, enabling ClickOnce and setting the build config to Release avoid the false positive from Qihoo, apparently now they mark those too as malware. I say just ignore Qihoo for now, their [behavior](http://vrworld.com/2015/05/04/qihoo-360-antivirus-cheating/) is unworthy for [security vendor](http://www.scmagazine.com/bribery-helped-criminals-whitelist-malware-in-chinese-antivirus-product/article/489101/)